# How to Get facebook user ID from app-scoped user ID?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I need to get the read facebook userId,
After login I get  app-scoped-userID and how could I get userId?

Comment: You can't.  That's the point of an app-scoped id.

Comment: I need to filter  feed and get posts made by me that is why I need to compare userId getting from  feed with logged in userId
How Could I do this,if I it isn't possible to get userId from
 app-scoped-id?

Comment: Where are you getting the feed results from?  Is the feed for the user who auth'd your app?

Comment: I get feed of special facebook page,and I need to get feeds posts by me

Comment: My question is, what access token is being used to get the page feed?  Is it not returning app scoped ids?